# How to start preferenceActivity part way down the hierarchy

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am working at API level 9 so can not use the new Preference Fragment stuff.

I have a preference activity getting the preferences from and xml file as per the api demos.  I have a hierarchy of preference screens so normaly to get to a preference you have to click though a top level screen.

As well as getting to all the preferences from my main menu I would like to be able to start the preference activity at one of the sub screens rather than the top screen so I can start it directly in one of the sub screens on say a click in an activity that that group of sub preferences is relervant to.

Anyone know if this is posible?  I would of thought that passing some data with the intent would be the way but I can not find anything saying this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here is what I have ended up with with Kurtis's help.

Basically in my code starting the Preferences activity I have no action for all the preferences and an action if you want just some of them.  The action needs to match the key on a preference or preferenceGroupe of some sort.

```
// all preferences
Intent launchPreferencesIntent = new Intent().setClass(this,
    PreferencesFromXml.class);
startActivity(launchPreferencesIntent);

// just key_trip_plot_control_preferences
Intent launchPreferencesIntent = new Intent(
    getString(R.string.key_trip_plot_control_preferences))
    .setClass(this, PreferencesFromXml.class);
startActivity(launchPreferencesIntent);
```

In my PreferencesFromXml class I always add the preferences from the xml but then if I have an action I search though the preferences looking for a matching key.  If I find one I removeAll preferences then add the matching one or it's children if it is a PreferenceGroupe back in.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    String act = getIntent().getAction();

    if (act != null) {
        Preference res = findPreferenceByKey(getPreferenceScreen(), act);
        if (res != null) {
            getPreferenceScreen().removeAll();
            if (res instanceof PreferenceGroup) {
                PreferenceGroup groupe = (PreferenceGroup) res;
                // add sub items
                for (int i = 0; i < groupe.getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
                    Preference pref = groupe.getPreference(i);
                    if (pref != null) {
                        getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(pref);
                    }
                }
            } else { // just add the item.
                getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(res);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected Preference findPreferenceByKey(PreferenceGroup in, String key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < in.getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
        Preference pref = in.getPreference(i);
        if (pref == null) {
            // should not happen
            Log.v(TAG, "findPreferenceByKey null pref i:" + i);
            return null;
        } else if (pref.hasKey() && pref.getKey().equals(key)) {
            return pref;
        } else if (pref instanceof PreferenceGroup) {
            // recurse
            Preference res = findPreferenceByKey((PreferenceGroup) pref,
                    key);
            if (res != null) {
                return res;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Preference Fragment is available to you through the android compatibility package: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Second, yes this is possible. When you're creating your fragment or acitvity (which ever you decide), use the addPreferencesFromIntent() method ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html#addPreferencesFromIntent%28android.content.Intent%29 ), and instead of adding the whole screen just add the subscreen you want.

Comment: Well it's reasuring that it is possible. You have also got me to a new bit in the documentation I was not looking at as it's API level 11 and I was filtering it out. Unfortunatly the paragraph on addPreferencesFromIntent() is as clear as mud. Some more googeling has found a couple of people trying to do what I am trying to do but no clear example.  My curent atempt gives a null pointer exception in preferencemanager.inflateFromIntent, so prosumably my Intent is not good.

Comment: Ok, so addPreferencesFromIntent may not do exactly what you're looking for. According to the documentation, you're supposed to use it by setting an explicit activity in the intent. That activities meta-data will then be queried and it's assumed that meta-data will have the preferences in it. One thing you could do is associated the sub-preference screen with a particular activity. The better option would probably be to include your own data in the intent, parse that data yourself and then do an addPreferencesByResource() with the resource being dependent on the data you passed.

Comment: OK I got the AddPreferencesFromIntent to execute, I had the metadata in the wrong place in my manifest. I now get the first screen up but on clicking on a subscreen I get ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2408): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application Which I saw someone else report. I have hacked around the problem by duplicating the xml file for the sub level I am interested in and making a new Activity for it. If I could put an include in the xml then this would be OK but that want work for me in the preference xml.

Comment: I almost have it working with calling addPreferencesFromResource twice for the all preferences activity with two non replicated xml files.  Not right yet but close I will give it some more time tommorow.

Comment: Because a PreferenceScreen class is a sublcass of the Preference class, this means you can completely decompose all your PreferenceScreens in xml. Then in code reconstruct them and combine them any way you want using the addPreference() method.

Comment: I was like @lfor and got an NPE when trying to inflateFromIntent. I changed my manifest meta-data from "METADATA_KEY_PREFERENCES" to "android.preference" and the issue is fixed

Comment: I'm pretty sure PreferenceFragment is still not in the compatibility library.