# Access a shared-preference listPreference directly, without having to enter the menu first! (Android)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have no idea how to achieve this, and don't know if it's achievable or not.

I have a sharedPreference value I set via my android app like this
menu button -> settings -> listPreference  (a 1 digit value is set this way, among 3 values!!!)

I would however like to be able to set this value without entering the settings menu first, because it is changed often. Im thinking a button should take me directly to the listPreference dialog box like this!
Button -> listPreference

Is is possible to omit the settings menu like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I asked somthing similar some time back.  There is no quick solution but I have a coded up custom solution in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676590/how-to-start-preferenceactivity-part-way-down-the-hierarchy)

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the answer. It does look a bit complex to be honest! I'll have to look more into the matter!

Comment: I actually ended up just making an alertDialog with a list inside, and directly from there write to SharedPreferences. That seemed as the easiest solution.